# How to prepare a new disk to restore a Windows 10 backup image?

Tags: backup, restore, windows-10, image

My current system (Windows 10 Pro) is on a 256 GB SSD and I want to replace that with a 500 GB one. So I read about that and found some articles suggesting using the systems build-in tools to move my complete system from one disk to the other.

So I used `Control Panel -> System and Security -> Backup and Restore (Windows 7) -> Create a system image` to backup my current system to another transfer-HDD which also has 500 GB of storage. It asked to also create a system restore boot CD which I did.

I then disconnected the original 256 GB SSD from my SATA port, connected the new 500 GB SSD instead, and booted from the CD.

There I selected restore image. It directly located the backup image on the transfer-HDD. The new 500 GB SSD is also found, as it is listed when I open the dialog to exclude drives (of course I did *not* check the disk to be excluded).

But when I start the process I get the following error message:

`Windows cannot create a disk on this computer needed to restore from the backup. Make sure the disks are properly connected, or add or change disks, and try the restore again Error: 0x80042402`

I did not find any troubleshooting hints so far.
What do I need to do so that the restore system can create the required partitions on the new SSD and 'create a disk' to restore the backup to?

In the meantime, I plugged the old small SSD back in and wait for some ideas and help :)

Answer (score -1):

to use fully possibility of microsoft you would require third drive. Backup 256Gb to 3rd drive . Swap drives -> restore to 500GB. But I wouldn't go with that much hustle just use for example : [http://www.todo-backup.com/backup-resource/free-disk-cloning-software.htm] or any other copying software

Comment: That is exactly what I did explain. I backed my original 256 GB SSD to a external 500 GB spinning metal HDD, and from that I wanted to restore to my new 500 GB SSD.